# ERROR Adminpaq & Contpaq SDK

Tags: vb.net, windows, sdk

Quiero usar un dll que esta en la ruta que obtengo del local machine, pero me sale un error; debugueando ahi marque donde me sale el error.

ERROR:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Codigo:

```
Try
        Dim lError As Integer
        Dim lNombrePAQ = ""
        Dim sLlaveSis = ""

        'Dim iSistema = 1 ' 0 = AdminPAQ, 1 = FACTURA, 2 = COMERCIAL

        Select Case cboSistema.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                ' AdminPAQ
                sLlaveSis = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Computación en Acción, SA CV\\AdminPAQ"
                lNombrePAQ = "AdminPAQ"
            Case 1
                ' CONTPAQ i FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA
                sLlaveSis = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Computación en Acción, SA CV\\CONTPAQ I Facturacion"
                lNombrePAQ = "CONTPAQ I Facturacion"
            Case 2
                ' CONTPAQ i COMERCIAL
                sLlaveSis = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Computación en Acción, SA CV\\CONTPAQ I COMERCIAL"
                lNombrePAQ = "CONTPAQ I COMERCIAL"
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Seleccione un sistema")
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        ' Establece la ruta donde se encuentar el archivo MGW_SDK.DLL dependiendo de la ruta del sistema leída en el registry.
        Dim lRutaBinarios = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(sLlaveSis, "DirectorioBase", Nothing)
        SetCurrentDirectory(lRutaBinarios)

        txtMsg.Text = "Inicializando SDK..."
        'Inicializa SDK
        lError = SDK.fSetNombrePAQ(lNombrePAQ)'AQUI ME SALE EL ERROR
        If lError <> 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(rError(lError))
            Exit Sub
        End If

        txtMsg.Text = "Se inicializó el SDK."
        cboSistema.Enabled = False
        btnAbrirEmpresa.Enabled = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Esta es la direccion del dll que quiero utilizar:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Compacw\AdminPAQ\MGW_SDK.dll
```

En la clase SDK tengo la funcion:

```
Public Declare Function fSetNombrePAQ Lib "MGW_SDK.DLL" (ByVal aNombrePAQ As String) As Integer
```

Si alguien a trabajando con el SDK de Adminpaq & Contpaq sabra mas o menos el uso de la dll.

Comment: ¿Estas intentando cargar una aplicación de 32 bits en una plataforma de 64? ¿Tienes habilitadas las aplicaciones de 32 bits en el sistema operativo?

Comment: El sistema operativo es de 64 bits, pero al instalarse en Program Files (x86) significa que es de 32 bits la aplicacion, como puedo habilitar aplicaciones de 32 bits en mi sistema?

Comment: Tal vez el problema es que estás usando un Sdk de 64 bits contra aplicaciones de 32. No conozco nada de Contpaq, has probado contactarlos o buscar en los foros de soporte?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho de echo estoy buscando informacion en sus foros de Compaq pero al parecer contestan hasta los 1500 dias :( y mi proveedor local solo da soporte a usuarios finales de la aplicacin y no a programadores o dudas mas tecnicas del uso del SDK

Comment: Despues de muchas semanas pude solucionarlo, pero si esta bien complicado integrar otros sistemas con el sdk, pondre mi respuesta mas adelante.

Comment: Como lograste solucionarlo? tengo ese mismo problema

Comment: @rodrigomx uff ya habia olvidado poner mi respuesta, pero lo unico que pude hacer es que ellos me mandaron un proyecto ya compilado con todo lo necesario para la conexion con el SDK en VB.net y lo integre a mi proyecto C#, basicamente tengo dos uno del sistema que yo realice y de ahi mando llamar el exe que si se conecta con el sdk y solamente asi pude mandar mis datos al adminpaq, la verddad esta todo bien truqueado esos sistemas y apenas ando implementando jajaja la proxima semana entra a produccion hoy toco hacer pruebas aun.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ejecutar el visual studio como administrador las carpetas del SDK de contpaq no son siempre accesibles sin derechos de admin.